# How can I use dd to write an image to my android phones SD card?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, dd, nook

I'm trying to use my android phone in place of a card reader to write a `.img` file to its external(removable) sd card(`/mnt/emc`) but when I try to do this from a terminal on the phone(`dd if=foobar.img of=/mnt/emmc`) dd complains that I'm writing to a directory.   The galaxy s2 mounts it's internal storage to `/mnt/sdcard`, and then mounts the external sd card as a directory inside of that.  Apparently using DD from a computer that has the SD mounted over USB will silently corrupt the image on write because of how the device shelters it's storage somehow.  Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can "dd" to a device, not to its mount point. `/mnt/emc` is a mount point, not a device.
`dd if=foobar.img of=/dev/mydevice`  would instead work.
Please use command `mount` to see which device corresponds to that mount point

Comment: Could you precise that the command `mount` is actually `/system/bin/mount` ? Could you also precise if it works without rooting?